# Git Bash/Git GUI некорректное отображение ярлыка

Tags: windows-7, git-bash

Установил Git-2.10.0-64-bit на Windows 7.
Проблема в  том что некорректно отображается ярлык в Пуске

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и при правом щелчке мышки на рабочем столе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что б отображался нормальный ярлык.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отображались верные значки в контекстном меню необходимо изменить два значения `Icon` в ветках реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\git_gui` и `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\git_shell`. Соответственно указать путь до какого-либо значка, например, `"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-gui\lib\git-gui.ico"`.

Answer (score 3):

На 7 у всех одна и та же хрень. На значек Git -> Свойства -> Сменить значек -> Ищещь на C:\ProgrammFiles\Git\ -> Выбираешь Git Bash или что есть и оно само тащит значек, вуаля

Comment: в контекстном меню так значёк не меняется, изменяется в Пуске